# Create non-duplicate cross product with custom column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this dataframe:

```
  Animal       Name Months
0    dog      Rosie     45
1    cat     Archie     12
2  snake  Archibald     14
```

Using this code

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['Name'], df1['Name']), columns=["id1","id2"])
new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
```

I'm able to create this table:

```
         id1        id2  LevScore
0      Rosie      Rosie         0
1      Rosie     Archie         4
2      Rosie  Archibald         8
3     Archie      Rosie         4
4     Archie     Archie         0
5     Archie  Archibald         4
6  Archibald      Rosie         8
7  Archibald     Archie         4
8  Archibald  Archibald         0
```

Which contains duplicate pairs (e.g. Rosie-Archie, Archie-Rosie)

Thus, I'm able to remove duplicate pairs using

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(combinations_with_replacement(df1['Name'], 2), columns=["id1","id2"])
new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
```

and I get this:

```
         id1        id2  LevScore
0      Rosie      Rosie         0
1      Rosie     Archie         4
2      Rosie  Archibald         8
4     Archie     Archie         0
5     Archie  Archibald         4
8  Archibald  Archibald         0
```

Next, instead of writing the full name of each animal in *id1* and *id2*, I would like to just have their row index. Rosie's row is on index 0, Archie's is on index 1, and Archibald's is on index 2. Thus, I would like to create the following table

```
    id1  id2  LevScore
0   0    0    0
1   0    1    4
2   0    1    8
4   1    1    0
5   1    2    4
8   2    2    0
```

Now, I would like to write to multiple columns. Say that the *levenshtein* function returns two values (distance and similarity score), I would like to write these two values to two different columns, such as this:

```
    id1  id2  LevScore  Similarity
0   0    0    0         1.00
1   0    1    4         0.45
2   0    1    8         0.32
4   1    1    0         1.00
5   1    2    4         0.89
8   2    2    0         1.00
```

Next, I would like to construct this dataframe so it only writes to it under a certain condition, such as that 'LevScore' < 6, in which case I would get the following dataframe:

```
    id1  id2  LevScore  Similarity
0   0    0    0         1.00
1   0    1    4         0.45
4   1    1    0         1.00
5   1    2    4         0.89
8   2    2    0         1.00
```

Lastly, I would like to not have texts (in this case, values in 'Name' column) consider themselves (because the Levenshtein distance will always be 0, which is useless information), so I would only really be left with:

```
    id1  id2  LevScore  Similarity
1   0    1    4         0.45
5   1    2    4         0.89
```

Is there any way to combine all of these into one efficient algorithm? I have a large dataset, where efficiency is really crucial. Thank you in advance!

Comment: From which package  `levenshtein` comes from?

Comment: leven, for example. It does not return two values, but just making an example that _if_ an arbitrary function were to return two values, I'd like to know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using your approach, you can directly use the index in `combinations` and reference the first dataframe in your `apply`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein

(pd.DataFrame(combinations_with_replacement(df1.index, 2),
             columns=["id1","id2"])
   .assign(distance=lambda d:d.apply(lambda r:
                                     levenshtein(df1.loc[r['id1'], 'Name'],
                                                 df1.loc[r['id2'], 'Name']),
                                     axis=1))
)
```

output:

```
   id1  id2  distance
0    0    0         0
1    0    1         4
2    0    2         8
3    1    1         0
4    1    2         4
5    2    2         0
```

###### older answer

You could apply a **cross** `merge` and filter your new dataframe in the beginning:

```
new_df = (
 df1.rename(columns={'Name': 'id1'})
    .merge(df1['Name'].rename('id2'), how='cross')
    .loc[lambda d: d['id1'].ne(d['id2'])]
)
```

output:

```
  Animal        id1  Months        id2
1    dog      Rosie      45     Archie
2    dog      Rosie      45  Archibald
3    cat     Archie      12      Rosie
5    cat     Archie      12  Archibald
6  snake  Archibald      14      Rosie
7  snake  Archibald      14     Archie
```

Then you can apply your levenshtein.

For example here calculating the distance (but you can adapt to any metric you want):

```
from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein
new_df = (
 df1.rename(columns={'Name': 'id1'})
    .merge(df1['Name'].rename('id2'), how='cross')
    .loc[lambda d: d['id1'].ne(d['id2'])]
    .assign(distance=lambda d: d.apply(lambda r: levenshtein(r['id1'], r['id2']), axis=1))
)
```

output:

```
  Animal        id1  Months        id2  distance
1    dog      Rosie      45     Archie         4
2    dog      Rosie      45  Archibald         8
3    cat     Archie      12      Rosie         4
5    cat     Archie      12  Archibald         4
6  snake  Archibald      14      Rosie         8
7  snake  Archibald      14     Archie         4
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How would it be possible to remove the duplicate pairs?(e.g. Rosie-Archie is being considered as well as Archie-Rosie, but I need only one of them, not both)

Comment: @You_Donut sorry I though you wanted the permutations, in this case the approach with itertools is fine. I'll update the answer with a new solution based on that

Comment: Is there any way to filter rows during the _combinationsWithReplacements_ itertools code block? So as to remove the ones with LevScore==0, or keep only the ones with LevScore < 5, for example.

Comment: As you need the result of the computation, you have to do it afterwards

Comment: Ah gotcha, makes sense. Thank you!